# Solr results not showing all content items in portal

Tags: solr

Using `Sitecore 10.1.2`

This is a fresh instance and I have created a few templates and some related content items.

I have rebuilt the indexes for `sitecore_master_index` & `sitecore_sxa_master_index`.

In the `Solr` portal, when I select either of them in core and run a query with no filters, it shows only one of the new content items.

I'm expecting it to list all the created items.

Have not created any custom indexes or any custom code related to search.

What should I configure to see all the content items in the search results.

[image]

Comment: While rebuilding the index, did you any errors in logs?

Comment: No errors while rebuilding indexes

Comment: please provide screenshot of Solr dashborad? Also verify if index core name in solr is same by looking into showconfig.aspx?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal. Added the snap. Sorry, did not understand. It will be the same name as listed in indexing manager..right? Pls let me know if u r referring to something else.

Comment: Just add the numbers 14383 in start, rows. You will see all your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows:

[image]

It means there are in total 14383 documents in solr (you can treat that as number of versions of items in any language).

You can also see that you only ask Solr to return first 10 results:

[image]

That's why you don't see your items.

If you want to make sure that your item really is indexed, you can run a query with `_group` key and use item id (lowercase, without `-` and without curly brackets). That will return all the versions of that single item from the index, e.g.

`_group:110d559fdea542ea9c1c8a5df7e70ef9`

[image]